# Print Fortran variables with the same names as builtin types in gdb

Tags: fortran, gdb

As far as I can tell, this is valid Fortran code:

```
program main
implicit none

type foo
    character(len=7) :: int = "Hello, "
end type foo

type(foo) :: f
character(len=5) :: character = "World"
character(len=1) :: real = "!"

print *,f%int
print *,character
print *,real

end program
```

It compiles in gfortran 9.3 and gives the expected output.

However gdb (version 8.2) refuses to print single variables:

```
(gdb) p real
Attempt to use a type name as an expression
(gdb) p f%int
A syntax error in expression, near `int'.
```

I can list all variables:

```
(gdb) info locals
character = 'World'
f = ( int = 'Hello, ' )
real = '!'
```

`int` is a curious case, because int is not actually a type name in Fortran and a local variable named `int` can be printed by gdb. But a struct member named `int` as in the example can't be printed. And if a local variable `int` does not exist, `p int` results in the same error message as `p real`, so I suspect its connected. This is also how I came across the problem, because the code base I'm working in has a struct with a member `int` that aggregates and hides some internal data that I want to look at.

I tried version 9.2 and `f%int` is printable. The others are the same.

I realize those variable names are questionable, but apart from changing them, which is difficult in this particular code base, is there a way to get gdb to print those variables?

Comment: As a workaround, you can do `p CHARACTER` and `p REAL`, if you haven't turned on case sensitivity..

Comment: Definitely a bug in old gdb version -- apart from upgrading gdb, you can try using the Python API to bypass the expression parsing to see if it helps.